# C++ Perfect Generic Abstract Factory with arbitrary Constructor Arguments

Tags: c++, abstract-factory

for unit testing, I'm trying to create a Factory which meets the following requirements:

- (1) It can create arbitrary objects (e.g. `Timer` and `TimerMock`)
- (2) It returns `unique_ptr`s to a Base class to these objects (e.g. `unique_ptr<TimerInterface>`)
- (3) The Factory itself can be passed around as a base class pointer too
- (4) It shall be possible to call any constructor to create the Object [edit1]using the same factory object[/edit1]

The purpose is to do dependency injection with this factories to be able to exchange objects that are not part of the test with mock objects.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

//"perfect factory method"
//usage: std::unique_ptr<Type> pt(create<Type>(Type-constructor-arguments));
template <typename Type, typename ... ConstructorArgs>
auto create(ConstructorArgs&& ... args){
    return std::make_unique<Type>(std::forward<ConstructorArgs>(args)...);
}

//Abstract Factory Base class
template<typename BaseType, typename ... ConstructorArgs>
class IFactory {
    public:
        virtual ~IFactory() = default;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseType> create(ConstructorArgs&& ... args) const = 0;
};

//Abstract Factory class
template <typename BaseType, typename DerivedType, typename ... ConstructorArgs>
class CFactory : public IFactory<BaseType, ConstructorArgs...>
{
    public:
        using Base = IFactory<BaseType, ConstructorArgs...>;
        std::unique_ptr<BaseType> create(ConstructorArgs&& ... args) const override
        {
            return ::create<DerivedType>(std::forward<ConstructorArgs>(args)...);
        }
};
```

How the real Factory classes are defined:

```
class TimerInterface {
    public:
        TimerInterface() = default;
        TimerInterface (const char* name);
        virtual void whoami() const = 0;
        /*...*/
};

class Timer: public TimerInterface {
    public:
        Timer() = default;
        Timer(const char* name) : TimerInterface (name) {}
        void whoami() const override { std::cerr << "I'm real!" << std::endl; }
        /*...*/
};


class TimerMock : public TimerInterface {
    public:
        TimerMock () = default;
        TimerMock (const char* name) : TimerInterface (name) {}
        void whoami() const override { std::cerr << "I fake it!" << std::endl; }
        /*...*/
};

using TimerFactory = CFactory<TimerInterface, Timer, const char*>;
using TimerMockFactory = CFactory<TimerInterface, TimerMock, const char*>;

using TimerFactoryInterface = TimerFactory::Base;
```

And how they are intended to be used:

```
class ClassUnderTest {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<TimerInterface> timer {};
        std::unique_ptr<TimerInterface> timer2 {};
    
        ClassUnderTest(const TimerFactoryInterface& factory)
        : timer(factory.create("I got a name!"))
        //, timer2(factory.create())
        {}
};

class Production
{
    public:
        ClassUnderTest realUsage;
        
        Production() :
        realUsage(TimerFactory())
        {}
};

class Test
{
    public:
        ClassUnderTest tested;
        
        Test() :
        tested(TimerMockFactory())
        {}  
};

int main()
{
    Production p;
    p.realUsage.timer->whoami();
    
    Test t;
    t.tested.timer->whoami();
}
```

My big problem is requirement (4)
ClassUnderTest::timer2 can't be created with the same factory that's used for ClassUnderTest::timer, beause the constructor signatur already needs to be known when defining the CFactory class.

Anyone got an idea?

P.S.: "It can't be done" with an explanation is also an acceptable answer, but not my favourite ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SparkyPotato gave me the idea when stating I'd "have to manually list out the possible constructors and generate overloads for create". I just disliked the *manually*, so I did it by template meta programming. Thanks for the hint!

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>


//"perfect factory method"
//usage: std::unique_ptr<Type> pt(create<Type>(Type-constructor-arguments));
template <typename Type, typename ... ConstructorArgs>
auto create(ConstructorArgs&& ... args){
    std::cerr << "calling " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return std::make_unique<Type>(std::forward<ConstructorArgs>(args)...);
}

//Abstract Factory Variadic class. This is also generic case that ends recursion
template <typename BaseType, typename TupleListOfConstructorArgs>
class IFactory
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<TupleListOfConstructorArgs, std::tuple<>>::value, "");
    public:
        //this method shall never be instatiated, it just exists to satisfy the "using BaseFactory::create" in IFactory
        template <typename T> void create(){ static_assert(sizeof(BaseType) + sizeof(T) < 0, ""); }
        virtual ~IFactory() = default;
};

//Abstract Factory Variadic class specialization to perform inheritance recursion
template <typename BaseType, typename ... CurrentTupleArgs, typename ... TupleListOfConstructorArgs>
class IFactory<BaseType, std::tuple<std::tuple<CurrentTupleArgs...>, TupleListOfConstructorArgs...>> : public IFactory<BaseType, std::tuple<TupleListOfConstructorArgs...>>
{
    public:
        using BaseFactory = IFactory<BaseType, std::tuple<TupleListOfConstructorArgs...>>;
        using BaseFactory::create;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseType> create(const CurrentTupleArgs&  ... args) const = 0;
};

//Concrete Factory Variadic class. This is also generic case that ends inheritance recursion
template <typename BaseType, typename DerivedType, typename TupleListOfConstructorArgs, typename FullTupleListOfConstructorArgs>
class CFactory : public IFactory<BaseType, FullTupleListOfConstructorArgs>
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<TupleListOfConstructorArgs, std::tuple<>>::value, "");
    public:
        using Base = IFactory<BaseType, FullTupleListOfConstructorArgs>;
};

//Concrete Factory Variadic class specialization to perform inheritance recursion
template <typename BaseType, typename DerivedType, typename ... CurrentTupleArgs, typename ... TupleListOfConstructorArgs, typename  FullTupleListOfConstructorArgs>
class CFactory<BaseType, DerivedType, std::tuple<std::tuple<CurrentTupleArgs...>, TupleListOfConstructorArgs...>, FullTupleListOfConstructorArgs> : public CFactory<BaseType, DerivedType, std::tuple<TupleListOfConstructorArgs...>, FullTupleListOfConstructorArgs>
{
    public:
        using BaseFactory = CFactory<BaseType, DerivedType, std::tuple<TupleListOfConstructorArgs...>, FullTupleListOfConstructorArgs>;
        using BaseFactory::create;

        std::unique_ptr<BaseType> create(const CurrentTupleArgs&  ... args) const override
        {
            std::cerr << "calling " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; 
            return ::create<DerivedType>(args...);
        }
};

template <typename BaseType, typename DerivedType, typename TupleListOfConstructorArgs>
using CFactoryFrontend = CFactory<BaseType, DerivedType, TupleListOfConstructorArgs, TupleListOfConstructorArgs>;

class TimerInterface {
    public:
        TimerInterface() = default;
        virtual ~TimerInterface() = default;
        TimerInterface (const char* name) {}
        TimerInterface(int& x, const char* name) { std::cerr << "calling " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;  }
        TimerInterface(const int& x, const char* name) { std::cerr << "calling " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;  }
        virtual void whoami() const = 0;
        /*...*/
};

class Timer: public TimerInterface {
    public:
        Timer() = default;
        Timer(const char* name) : TimerInterface (name) {}
        Timer(int& x, const char* name) : TimerInterface(x, name) {}
        Timer(const int& x, const char* name) : TimerInterface(x, name) {}
        void whoami() const override { std::cerr << "I'm real!" << std::endl; }
        /*...*/
};


class TimerMock : public TimerInterface {
    public:
        TimerMock () = default;
        TimerMock (const char* name) : TimerInterface (name) {}
        TimerMock (int& x, const char* name) : TimerInterface(x, name) {}
        TimerMock (const int& x, const char* name) : TimerInterface(x, name) {}
        void whoami() const override { std::cerr << "I fake it!" << std::endl; }
        /*...*/
};

//using TimerInterfaceConstructors = std::tuple<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<const char*>>;
using Constructors = std::tuple<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<const char*>, std::tuple<int&, const char*>, std::tuple<const int&, const char*>>;

using TestFactory = CFactoryFrontend<TimerInterface, Timer, Constructors>;

using TimerFactory = CFactoryFrontend<TimerInterface, Timer, Constructors>;
using TimerMockFactory = CFactoryFrontend<TimerInterface, TimerMock, Constructors>;

using TimerFactoryInterface = TimerFactory::Base;


class ClassUnderTest {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<TimerInterface> timer {};
        std::unique_ptr<TimerInterface> timer2 {};
    
        ClassUnderTest(const TimerFactoryInterface& factory)
        : timer(factory.create("I got a name!"))
        , timer2(factory.create())
        {}
};

class Production
{
    public:
        ClassUnderTest realUsage;
        
        Production() :
        realUsage(TimerFactory())
        {}
};

class Test
{
    public:
        ClassUnderTest tested;
        
        Test() :
        tested(TimerMockFactory())
        {}  
};

int main()
{
    Production p;
    p.realUsage.timer->whoami();
    
    Test t;
    t.tested.timer->whoami();

    TestFactory tf;
    TimerFactoryInterface& tfi(tf);

    const char* x = "X";
    tfi.create();
    tfi.create(x);

    int y;
    const int cy = 17;
    tfi.create(y, x);
    tfi.create(cy, "name");

    ::create<Timer>(x);
}
```

It compiles using GCC-6 and newer and clang with -std=c++-14

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but `TimerInterface` doesn't need to be a complete type when you declare your two `std::unique_ptr<TimerInterface>` inside `ClassUnderTest`. Meaning this is legal:

```
    // classundertest.hpp

    // A forward-declaration is enough
    class TimerInterface;
    class TimerFactoryInterface;

    class ClassUnderTest {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<TimerInterface> timer {};
        std::unique_ptr<TimerInterface> timer2 {};
    
    // Both MUST be declared here AND defined in the .cpp for this trick to work
    ClassUnderTest(const TimerFactoryInterface& factory);
    ~ClassUnderTest();
```

```
    // classundertest.cpp

    #include "classundertest.hpp"

    // TimerInterface wasn't truly declared until now
    #include "TimerInterface.hpp"

    ClassUnderTest::ClassUnderTest(const TimerFactoryInterface& factory)
    : timer(factory.create("I got a name!"))
    , timer2(factory.create("???"))
    {}

    ClassUnderTest::~ClassUnderTest() 
    {}
```

That's basically how unique_ptr-based [pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) work.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't even address the question. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `std::vector<std::any>`, and some index sequences, but it isn't going to be the most pretty or fast solution.

Your factory would be:

```
template<typename Base>
class IFactory
{
public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> Create(const std::vector<std::any>& args) const = 0;
};
```

Your concrete factory could then be:

```
template<typename Base, typename Derived, typename... Args>
class CFactory : IFactory<Base>
{
private:
  template<size_t... Indices>
  std::unique_ptr<Base> Make(const std::vector<std::any>& args, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) const
  {
    return std::make_unique<Derived>(std::any_cast<Args>(args[Indices])...);
  }

public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> Create(const std::vector<std::any>& args) const
  {
    return Make(args, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
  }
};
```

The only problem here is that you obviously cannot perfectly forward any arguments, you will always end up taking a copy.
It will also throw an `std::bad_any_cast` if the types passed into the `std::any` do not match the template.

Here's a simple test I made, and it compiles with both MSVC and Clang with `-std=c++17` set:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a, int b)
        : Val1(a), Val2(b)
    {}
    
    A(int a)
        : Val1(a), Val2(0)
    {}
    
    int Val1, Val2;
    
};

int main()
{
    CFactory<A, A, int> fac1;
    CFactory<A, A, int, int> fac2;
    
    auto a1 = fac1.Create({ std::any(10) });
    auto a2 = fac2.Create({ std::any(10), std::any(20) });
    
    std::cout << a1->Val1 << " " << a1->Val2 << "\n";
    std::cout << a2->Val1 << " " << a2->Val2 << "\n";
}
```

Edit: This will work for overloaded constructors, as well as any type because its template magic.

Comment: Thanks, but this implementation has the same problem as mine: I need two different factory types to construct timer and timer2. I'd like to use the *same* factory object.

Comment: @ReneB By requirement 4 I understood that you would want to choose constructor overloads. The way you want is not possible, as there is no way for the compiler to deduce the type you want the create function to actually construct.

Comment: I want to give the using class (`ClassUnderTest`) the freedom to choose the constructor itself, just like it could when instantiating the object directly. Currently the "parent" class (`Production`/`Test`) is deciding which Constructor `ClassUnderTest` has to use

Comment: @ReneB You'd have to use some (more) template metaprogramming, and manually list out the possible constructors and then generate overloads for `Create`. You can also try to add another level of type-erasure, but I don't think that'll work.

Comment: Listing `create(...)`-overloads isn't generic. I already tried a double-dispatch, but that would require multiple `create(...)`-overloads, too.

Comment: I'm still hoping for a lambda/functor/std::any/std::bind/std::function solution :D
Anything that helps

Comment: What you're asking for is pretty much templated virtual functions, which aren't possible.

Comment: Actually yes, I'm looking for a way to do that :D
Simplest solution would be templating `ClassUnderTest`, but I'm afraid that would grow very fast, which is why I'm trying to get a polymorphic solution